# SQL - How to do Window function if there is NULL value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

First, I have this information:

1. Weight A
2. Weight B
3. Relationship B to A: 1 to Many

Such that, below result can be obtained:

| A_Id | Weight A | Weight B | B_Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 16 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 16 | 1 |
| 3 | 6 | 16 | 1 |
| 4 | 7 | 16 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 12 | 2 |
| 6 | 6 | 12 | 2 |

Now, adding two more columns: `Sum Weight A By B_Id`, `Accumulative Difference`
(consider below as table `t2`)

| A_Id | Weight A | Sum Weight A By B_Id | Weight B | B_Id | Accumulative Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 21 | 16 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 5 | 21 | 16 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 | 21 | 16 | 1 | 5 |
| 4 | 7 | 21 | 16 | 1 | 5 |
| 5 | 2 | 8 | 12 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 6 | 8 | 12 | 2 | 1 |

For example above,

1. first row accumulative difference => 21 - 16 = 5
2. the fifth row accumulative difference => (21 + 8) - (16 + 12) = 1

**So, my objective, is to compute such '`Accumulative Difference`'** The entire result is to be displayed in the report.

Technically, by using 'Window Functions', this can be achieved without problem.
<strike>First, I have to create 2 more columns: `Accumulate Weight A By B_Id`, `Accumulate Weight B`. Then, just find the difference between the two.</strike>

I actually need 3 more columns:

- [Row By B_Id]
- [Sum Weight A By B_Id]
- [Accumulate Weight B]

| A_Id | Weight A | Sum Weight A By B_Id | Weight B | B_Id | Row By B_Id | Accumulate Weight A By B_Id | Accumulate Weight B | Accumulative Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 21 | 16 | 1 | 1 | 21 | 16 | 5 |
| 2 | 5 | 21 | 16 | 1 | 2 | 21 | 16 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 | 21 | 16 | 1 | 3 | 21 | 16 | 5 |
| 4 | 7 | 21 | 16 | 1 | 4 | 21 | 16 | 5 |
| 5 | 2 | 8 | 12 | 2 | 1 | 29 | 28 | 1 |
| 6 | 6 | 8 | 12 | 2 | 2 | 29 | 28 | 1 |

sample SQL (to generate`t2`):

<strike>SELECT 
     *,
     [Accumulate Weight A By B_Id] = SUM(WeightA) OVER (PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY B_Id),
     [Accumulate Weight B] = SUM(WeightB) OVER (PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY B_Id)
    FROM t2
    -- (...) could be by date year month
    -- Accumulate Weight B can set to only 1st row, etc</strike>

```
;WITH tableA AS (
SELECT [A_Id] = 1, [Weight] = 3, [B_Id] = 1, [date] = '2021-10-01'
UNION
SELECT [A_Id] = 2, [Weight] = 5, [B_Id] = 1, [date] = '2021-10-02'
UNION
SELECT [A_Id] = 3, [Weight] = 6, [B_Id] = 1, [date] = '2021-10-03'
UNION
SELECT [A_Id] = 4, [Weight] = 7, [B_Id] = 1, [date] = '2021-10-04'
UNION
SELECT [A_Id] = 5, [Weight] = 2, [B_Id] = 2, [date] = '2021-10-05'
UNION
SELECT [A_Id] = 6, [Weight] = 6, [B_Id] = 2, [date] = '2021-10-06'
    
--Uncomment for testing NULL value
--UNION
--SELECT [A_Id] = 7, [Weight] = 9, [B_Id] = NULL, [date] = '2021-10-07'
--UNION
--SELECT [A_Id] = 8, [Weight] = 10, [B_Id] = 3, [date] = '2021-10-08'
    
),
tableB AS (
     SELECT [B_Id] = 1, [Weight] = 16, [date] = '2021-10-03'
     UNION
     SELECT [B_Id] = 2, [Weight] = 12, [date] = '2021-10-06'

    --Uncomment for testing NULL value
    --UNION
    --SELECT [B_Id] = 3, [Weight] = 8, [date] = '2021-10-08'
),
t1a AS (
    SELECT 
        [A_Id] = tableA.A_Id,
        [WeightA] = tableA.Weight,
        [WeightB] = tableB.Weight,
        [B_Id] = tableB.B_Id,
        [Row By B_Id] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tableB.B_Id ORDER BY A_Id)
    FROM 
        tableA 
    FULL JOIN tableB ON tableA.B_Id = tableB.B_Id
),
t1b AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        [Sum Weight A By B_Id] = SUM(WeightA) OVER (ORDER BY B_Id),
        [Accumulate Weight B] = SUM(CASE WHEN [Row By B_Id] = 1 THEN WeightB ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY B_Id)
    FROM t1a
),
t2 AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        [Accumulate Difference] = [Sum Weight A By B_Id] - [Accumulate Weight B]
    FROM t1b
)
SELECT 
    *
FROM t2
```

Now, the problem comes, IF one of the `B_Id` is `NULL`. (Uncomment the parts to generate NULL B_Id)

**Below is my expected result**, especially on the highlighted row:

| A_Id | Weight A | Sum Weight A By B_Id | Weight B | B_Id | Accumulate Weight A By B_Id | Accumulate Weight B | Accumulative Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 21 | 16 | 1 | 21 | 16 | 5 |
| 2 | 5 | 21 | 16 | 1 | 21 | 16 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 | 21 | 16 | 1 | 21 | 16 | 5 |
| 4 | 7 | 21 | 16 | 1 | 21 | 16 | 5 |
| 5 | 2 | 8 | 12 | 2 | 29 | 28 | 1 |
| 6 | 6 | 8 | 12 | 2 | 29 | 28 | 1 |
| **7** | **9** | **9** | **0** | **NULL** | **38** | **28** | **10** |
| 8 | 7 | 10 | 8 | 3 | 48 | 36 | 12 |
| 9 | 3 | 10 | 8 | 3 | 48 | 36 | 12 |

However, with my sample query, this is not working. Instead, below appears:

[image: current result]

The NULL B_Id appears on the first row instead. (The order is messed up)

So my question, how to handle such situation? (Keep the original row as in the expected result)

As why the order is in such as way? (raised by @ThorstenKettner)

The order by default, is based `B_TransactionDatetime`. If `B_Id` is NULL, then it will be based on `A_TransactionDatetime`. So, I compute another column `RefDateTime = COALESCE(B_TransactionDatetime, A_TransactionDatetime)`, and order based on that.

**PS:**

Inspired by @ThorstenKettner, i should use the `RefDateTime` in the window function, i.e:

```
[Sum Weight A By B_Id] = SUM(WeightA) OVER (ORDER BY RefDateTime),
[Accumulate Weight B] = SUM(CASE WHEN [Row By B_Id] = 1 THEN WeightB ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY RefDateTime)
```

Case closed.

Comment: Are you using `-` to represent `NULL`s here? It would be less confusing it you used `NULL`. `'-'` is a string, which would imply you are storing numerical data in a `varchar`; a major design flaw.

Comment: You talk about a set of data with a `B_Id` of `NULL` as well, but none of your sample data demonstrates this problem.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for the feedback. i just added a column `B_Id`. Meanwhile, the '-' is not NULL, you can consider it is the same value as the previous row. (i put hyphen to focus other values)

Comment: YOu need to correct your data then, zeroflaw. `-` <> `The value of the previous row`. If multiple rows all have the same value, they should do too in your sample data.

Comment: @Larnu Sure. corrected as mentioned. also, added missing `B_Id` in other table

Comment: The sample data doesn't have any rows with a value of `NULL` for `B_ID` though. So where is this `NULL` value coming from?

Comment: @Larnu in last table, the highlighted row (7th row)

Comment: I was under the impression that was your expected results, @Zeroflow, apologies,.

Comment: @zeroflaw What values would you expect to see for the row with `B_ID` as `NULL` instead of the ones shown?

Comment: So there are A without a B. I don't understand though, by what criteria you order your rows. At first I though by b.id, a.weight, but the position of b.id NULL contradicts that as well as the order the rows for b.id 3.

Comment: @ggordon The table shown is the expected result. But i couldnt achieve with the sample SQL query.

Comment: So if that *is* your expected results, where is the sample data, @zeroflaw ? I'm confused again.

Comment: Ok guys. Sorry for the confusion. I will amend this post tomorrow to ensure all things are conveyed properly.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes i understand your question. let me edit this tomorrow for clearer info.

Comment: @Larnu , I have added 'exact' query to generate the result. Also, added other missing info. Hopefully everything is much clearer now

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i added at last part of the question. Basically the order is by transaction datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to outer join B to A, because not every A has an associated B.

Then you look at the rows blockwise. One block is either all rows.belonging to one B or a single A row that doesn't have a B. The b_id would make a good group key for the former, while the a_id would be appropriate for the latter. For the combined key there are different options. `COALESCE(b_id, a_id)` isn't one of them, because we could have an a_id 1 and a b_id 1 in the result set, but don't want them in the same group. One solution is a simple `COALESCE(b_id, -a_id)`, provided your IDs cannot be negative, of course.

Now, all your calculations are based on the aggregated groups, I.e. you are not interested in single A values when they belong to a B group. For this reason I'd aggregate immediately and only join the single A rows again at the very end.

The order of the rows is `COALESCE(b_date, a_date)`.

```
 with grouped as
    (
      select
        coalesce(b.b_id, -a.a_id) as grp_id,
        max(coalesce(b.date, a.date)) as grp_date,
        coalesce(max(b.weight), 0) as b_weight,
        sum(a.weight) as a_weight
      from a
      left join b on b.b_id =a.b_id
      group by coalesce(b.b_id, -a.a_id)
    )
    , calculated as
    (
      select
        grp_id,
        grp_date,
        b_weight,
        a_weight,
        sum(a_weight - b_weight) over (order by grp_date) as running_diff
        from grouped
    )
    select *
    from calculated c
    join a on a.b_id = c.grp_id or a.a_id = -c.grp_id
    order by c.grp_date, a.date;
```

I hope I've got everything right. I don't have a computer at hand and am typing this on my mobile, which turns out harder than I thought :-)

Comment: Please someone edit this code for me. It doesn't work from my mobile phone. There is no `{}` button and the four-blanks indention doesn't seem to work properly for me either.

Comment: I have edited for you :) Your answer has inspired me on using the `RefDateTime` `COALESCE(b_date, a_date)` to be `ORDERed` in the window function. (that would do the job). Meanwhile, i have learnt that `COALESCE(b_id, -a_id)` can serve as a group. Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use coalesce().

```
SELECT 
 *,
 [Accumulate Weight A By B_Id] = SUM(WeightA) OVER (PARTITION BY B_id ORDER BY B_Id),
 [Accumulate Weight B] = SUM(WeightB) OVER (PARTITION BY B_id ORDER BY B_Id),
 SUM(coalesce(WeightA,0)-coalesce(WeightB,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY B_id ORDER BY B_Id) difference

FROM t2
```

PS: Actually your initial query looks wrong to me, if that was correct then this would do.
Probably you should give sample data of A and B. To me it makes more sense to sum() before joining them at all.

Comment: Hi, my apology. I have added more info in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make changes but this should help.`

```
SELECT [Accumulate Weight A By B_Id] = SUM(WeightA) OVER (
        PARTITION BY...ORDER BY B_Id
        )
    ,[Accumulate Weight B] = SUM(WeightB) OVER (
        PARTITION BY...ORDER BY B_Id
        )
FROM t2
WHERE B_Id IS NOT NULL

UNION

SELECT [Accumulate Weight A By B_Id] = SUM(TAB.WeightA) OVER (
        PARTITION BY TAB.ROW_NUM ORDER BY B_Id
        )
    ,[Accumulate Weight B] = SUM(TAB.WeightB) OVER (
        PARTITION BY TAB.ROW_NUM ORDER BY B_Id
        )
FROM (
    SELECT WeightA
        ,WeightB
        ,B_Id
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY B_ID
            ) AS ROW_NUM
    FROM T2
    WHERE B_ID IS NULL
    ) TAB
```

`

Comment: Hi, my apology. i have added more info in the question. As seen from your query, does it mean, finally, the order will change?